# Node.js, Express.js, Unexpected End of Input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, syntax

I am completely new to Express and Node.js. I am trying to experiment with both of these components a bit but I keep getting an error of Unexpected En of Input and I can't seem to fix it for the life of me!

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http')
var Raven = require('raven')
var shippo = require('shippo')('ACCESS_TOKEN')
var engines = require('consolidate')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.engine('html', engines.mustache)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
//app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname,'/')))


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('Index.html')
})
app.post('/', function (req, res) {

  var addressFrom  = {
      "name": "SENDER_NAME",
      "company":"Shippo",
      "street1":"215 Clayton St.",
      "city":"San Francisco",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"94117",
      "country":"US", //iso2 country code
      "phone":"+1 555 341 9393",
      "email":"SENDER_EMAIL"
  };

// example address_to object dict
  var addressTo = {
    "name": "Mr Hippo",
    "street1": "Broadway 1",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zip": "10007",
    "country": "US",
    "phone": "+1 555 341 9393",
    "email": "mrhippo@goshippo.com"
  };

  // parcel object dict
  var parcel = {
      "length":"5",
      "width":"5",
      "height":"5",
      "distance_unit":"in",
      "weight":"2",
      "mass_unit":"lb"
  };


  var shipment = shippo.shipment.create({
    "address_from": addressFrom,
    "address_to": addressTo,
    "parcels": [parcel],
    "carrier_account": 'CARRIER_TOKEN',
    "async": false
  });



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

**I keep getting the following error:**

[Link to ScreenShot of ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZHhs.png)

It says there's a ';' in line 70, but there isn't even a line 70 in my code. I've made sure that each parenthesis and opening elements match up but I still get this "Unexpected End of Input" error. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You aren't closing this: `app.post('/', function (req, res) {`

Comment: @MarkMeyer thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a `})` after shipment variable declaration to close `app.post('/', function(req, res) {`